# How to check if there are any files with a specific extension

Tags: c++, qt

I want to check if a directory has any files with a .tif extension? If there are any .tif files I will convert them. I start by checking if the users entry is equal to a tif (index 0).  Then I would check directory folder if there are any tif.  I am using a QDir with QfileInfoList. I don't think I am using the QfileInfoList properly as nothing happens.  Last, If Ext is greater than 0 convert the tif.

```
if (ui.SourceElev->currentIndex()== 0){

        QDir dir("C:/Terrain/Ned/");
        QFileInfoList Ext = dir.entryInfoList(QStringList() << ".tif", QDir::Files);

        if (Ext.size() > 0) {
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the wildcard and only returning files that are named exactly .tif. Change `".tif"` (exactly .tif) to `"*.tif"` (anything ending in .tif) and see if that helps.

Comment: Quick google suggests I may be right. See [Filter QFileInfoList files with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4364513/4581301)

Comment: You know, sometimes it is the little things that get you!   Problem Solved  Thank you!